# MongoServerError: query requires text score metadata, but it is not available

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

After migrating data from mongodb 4.2 to 6 and updating mongoose package to 6.11.1 got error **MongoServerError: query requires text score metadata, but it is not available**
example code below:

```
    async.parallel({
            total: cb => user.countDocuments(parameters).exec(cb),
            users: cb => user.find(parameters, {password: 0,selected_catalogs:0 ,**score: {$meta: "textScore"}}**,{skip: (page-1)*limit, limit: limit}).populate('rate').sort(sort).lean().exec(cb),
        }, (err, results) => {
            console.log(err);
            if (err) return res.status(400).json(err);
            // results.users = results.users.sort((a,b)=>{return a.score < b.score ? 1 : a.score > b.score ? -1 : 0});
            Consume.setUsersConsume(results.users).then(users => {
                let pages = Math.ceil(results.total/limit);
                users = _.sortBy(users, sort_by);

                if (sort_direction === -1) users.reverse();

                return res.json({
                    total: results.total,
                    per_page: limit,
                    current_page: page,
                    last_page: pages,
                    next_page_url: (page + 1) > pages ? null : 'http://' + config.get('external.main.api.url') + '/billing/users?page=' + (page + 1),
                    prev_page_url: (page - 1) < 1 ? null : 'http://' + config.get('external.main.api.url') + '/billing/users?page=' + (page - 1),
                    from: (page-1)*limit + 1,
                    to: ((page-1)*limit + limit) > results.total ?  results.total : ((page-1)*limit + limit),
                    users,
                    rates: rates
                }).end();
            }, error => {
                return res.status(500).json(error);
            });
        });
```

If I remove **score: {$meta: "textScore"}}** - all works fine, except sorting
Can anyone help with this?

P.S. collection have text index:

```
{
"key": {
  "_fts": "text",
  "_ftsx": 1
},
"name": "text_cmpName_cName_cPhone_cDopPhone_email",
"v": 2,
"default_language": "english",
"language_override": "language",
"textIndexVersion": 3,
"weights": {
  "company.name": 1,
  "contact.dopPhone": 1,
  "contact.name": 1,
  "contact.phone": 1,
  "email": 1
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share the `parameters` passed to the `find` function for matching documents.

Comment: problem with project (second object) after parameters. you think problem in params?

Comment: yeah, it might be there